# "Nose" is to "nasal" as "throat" is to what?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, analogy

We use *nasal* as an adjective for something related to *nose*.
What is the word to refer to something related to *throat*?

Comment: Are you looking for 'laryngeal'?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Throaty* and *gular* both mean "of the throat" with different nuances and different senses coming most immediately to mind.

*Glottal*, *guttural*, *laryngeal*, and *tracheal* are all related to parts of the throat, and hence more appropriate in some cases, while inaccurate in others.

Comment: *Pharyngeal* as well.

Comment: Yes, there are a lot more linguistic things one can do in the throat than in the nose.

Comment: Though that's really because there's more biological bits to a throat than a nose. Of the above, *tracheal* refers to the trachea, *glottal* to the glottis (the vocal chords and the space between them) and so on.

Comment: Yes. There's more bits that can get wiggled in speech. The nose can be turned on or off (occasionally there are three or more degrees of freedom, as in Acehnese, but mostly it's binary), and that's all. But there are dozens of possibilities with glottalization, pharyngealization, creaky voice, breathy voice, voicing itself, etc. -- all using the throat as an instrument, rather than just one stop of many.

Answer (score 7):

The Latin for *throat* is *gula*, and its adjective is *gular*. [Reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gular_skin)

However it's more usual in humans to narrow down the area of the throat in question: epiglottal, laryngeal, tracheal, and so on. [Wikipedia on the throat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Throat)

Comment: _Throat_ would sometimes be the correct answer here. Although probably best not considered an adjective, the noun-modifier usage can parallel the adjectival nasal: _He had a nasal / throat infection_.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I'd say that counts as an answer. And a very relevant and appropriate one at that. I would prefer *throat infection* to anything-*itis*, just as most doctors today.